# SQL Server Execution Plan Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have two servers I'm doing development on and I'm not a DBA, but we don't have one so I'm trying to figure out some performance issues I'm having.  Locally I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and when an ORM that I'm using runs a query it returns the results in less than a second.  When I run that exact same query on our development server with is SQL Server 2005, it takes over a minute.  I've looked at the execution plan on both of them the main thing that sticks out is the last two lines of the query has a order by statement.  On the 2005 server this is 100% of the cost. on the 2008 server its 0% of the cost.  Is there some sort of setting I'm overlooking?  Both servers have approximately the same data in them and the same indexes/keys/etc.....since the local copy is just a restore from a backup.

My best guess is the 2005 server is sorting all the tables and then giving me the results (200 lines).  Where the 2008 server is getting all the results and then sorting them. (200 results also.)

Link to slow execution plan: http://pastebin.com/sUCiVk8j

Link to fast execution plan: http://pastebin.com/EdR7zFAn

I would post the query but it is obnoxiously long because I have a bunch of includes and its Entity Framework that is generating the query.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:  I opened Task manager on the SQL server this is running on and the CPU goes to 100% during the execution of this query.

Edit:  Added XML version to jsfiddle.net.  pastebin wouldn't allow me to because of the size.  Just used the CSS window for the XML.

Actual 2008R2: http://jsfiddle.net/wgsv6/2/ 
Actual 2005: http://jsfiddle.net/wgsv6/3/

Comment: Sorting 200 rows shouldn't be responsible for this time difference so the estimated costs seem way off. Maybe the stats need updating on the 2005 server. The costs shown on both versions of the plans are just estimates based on these stats. Any discrepancies between estimated and actual rows in the plans?

Comment: also are these ACTUAL or ESTIMATED exec plans?

Comment: Agreed with @JNK - until we see some details, all we can do is speculate. Wildly.

Comment: Do both queries return quicker if you don't use `ORDER BY`? or are they still the same proportion? Are there any other major differences in the plans (e.g. does the slow one have extra sort operators)?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand  - without the order by clause the slow server performs MUCH faster.  Less than 10 seconds.  On the fast server it is smaller improvement obviously since it is already pretty fast.

Comment: @JNK posted the execution plan.

Comment: Can you paste the XML version of the actual execution plans? Doubt many people will fancy ploughing through that version.

Comment: @Kyle - OK that is the estimated plan. Do you have the actual plans for both servers? Also the cost shown in the plan is based on an estimate that it is going to be sorting 61,439,100 rows. This figure is woefully incorrect I assume as you said a couple of hundred above...

Comment: I will get the plans soon. Right now we have about 1.3 million interfaces in our Db. This returns 200 for a specific host. I noticed that 61 M number myself and have no idea where it came from.

Comment: @Kyle - The actual plan has both estimated and actual rows so hopefully there will be one place in the plan with a big discrepancy that it all propagates from.

Comment: @Martin Smith ok.  Actual plans uploaded to jsfiddle

Comment: Still looking at them but first thing I notice is the 2005 version has a much lower memory grant than the 2008 one. Can you see any hash warnings or sort warnings in Profiler when running this query?

Comment: Also seems to have a lot of hash joins with predicates on things like `Expr1271 = Expr1270` are all the joins on unsargable predicates?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the query, but is it possible you are missing an INDEX on the slow server?

Comment: It's possible, but the OP did say "same indexes/keys etc"... I'm going to guess it's one of three things - bad estimate due to out-of-date stats, parameter sniffing, or an unnecessary sort due to a poor operator choice (which may be due to one of the above). But it would be nice to see actual plans before guessing.

Comment: Ah missed that somehow, thanks.  In that case one of the things you listed is probably it.

Answer (score 0):

THe statistics could be out of date on the dev server.

Comment: I ran 'EXEC sp_updatestats' a couple hours ago right after I asked the question.  It didn't change any results.